# How to Unit Test Startup.cs in .NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

How do people go about Unit Testing their Startup.cs classes in a .NET Core 2 application? All of the functionality seems to be provided by Static extensions methods which aren't mockable?

If you take this `ConfigureServices` method for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

How can I write tests to ensure that `AddDbContext(...)` & `AddMvc()` are called - the choice of implementing all of this functionality via extension methods seems to have made it untestable?

Comment: For this cases I write integration tests to get the complete pipeline tested. You could use some.g. IoC to inject some functionality which you can mock.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well yes, if you want to check the fact that extension method `AddDbContext` was called on `services` you are in trouble.
The good thing is that you shouldn't actually check exactly this fact.

`Startup` class is an application [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). And when testing a composition root you want to check that it actually registers all dependencies required for instantiation of the root objects (controllers in the case of ASP.NET Core application).

Say you have following controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public TestController(ISomeDependency dependency)
    {
    }
}
```

You could try checking whether `Startup` has registered the type for `ISomeDependency`. But implementation of `ISomeDependency` could also require some other dependencies that you should check.
Eventually you end up with a test that has tons of checks for different dependencies but it does not actually guarantee that object resolution will not throw missing dependency exception. There is not too much value in such a test.

An approach that works well for me when testing a composition root is to use real dependency injection container. Then I call a composition root on it and assert that resolution of the root object does not throw.

It could not be considered as pure Unit Test because we use other non-stubbed class. But such tests, unlike other integration tests, are fast and stable. And most important they bring the value of valid check for correct dependencies registration. If such test passes you could be sure that object will also be correctly instantiated in the product.

Here is a sample of such test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConfigureServices_RegistersDependenciesCorrectly()
{
    //  Arrange

    //  Setting up the stuff required for Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    Mock<IConfigurationSection> configurationSectionStub = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
    configurationSectionStub.Setup(x => x["DefaultConnection"]).Returns("TestConnectionString");
    Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration> configurationStub = new Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration>();
    configurationStub.Setup(x => x.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")).Returns(configurationSectionStub.Object);

    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    var target = new Startup(configurationStub.Object);

    //  Act

    target.ConfigureServices(services);
    //  Mimic internal asp.net core logic.
    services.AddTransient<TestController>();

    //  Assert

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var controller = serviceProvider.GetService<TestController>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(controller);
}
```

Comment: Thanks CodeFuller, it was the concrete version of the ServiceCollection I was missing, I can just let the collection be built then validate the output to confirm that correct calls have been made. Nice one!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like this at all - why would you mock the ConfigurationSection? Rather than using the inbuilt one?

Then using the InMemory provider to get sections?

Answer (score 16):

I also had a similar problem, but managed to get around that by using the WebHost in AspNetCore and essentially re-creating what program.cs does, and then Asserting that all of my services exist and are not null. You could go a step further and execute specific extensions for IServices with .ConfigureServices or actually perform operations with the services you created to make sure they were constructed properly.

One key, is I created a unit test startup class that inherits from the startup class I'm testing so that I don't have to worry about separate assemblies. You could use composition if you prefer to not use inheritance.

```
[TestClass]
public class StartupTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void StartupTest()
    {
        var webHost = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
        Assert.IsNotNull(webHost);
        Assert.IsNotNull(webHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IService1>());
        Assert.IsNotNull(webHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IService2>());
    }
}

public class Startup : MyStartup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration config) : base(config) { }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my testing needs - thanks man

Comment: Couldn't make this work because i had `IHost`. Ended up with this: `var host = Program.CreateHostBuilder<Startup>(Array.Empty<string>()).Build();` Added a Type parameter to Program, so in tests I can swap it out.

Comment: @YarekT Thanks Yarek, I only showed in my answer WebHost, but you're right, if you are working with an IHost you can do exactly what you showed there and then retrieve your services like so:

```var config = (IConfiguration)host.Services.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));```

Comment: How do you pass appsettings.json configurations in this case?

Answer (score 4):

This approach works, and uses the real MVC pipeline, as things should only be mocked if you need to change how they work.

```
public void AddTransactionLoggingCreatesConnection()
{
     var servCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    //Add any injection stuff you need here
    //servCollection.AddSingleton(logger.Object);

    //Setup the MVC builder thats needed
    IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder = new MvcBuilder(servCollection, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager());

    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> confValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TransactionLogging:Enabled", "True"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TransactionLogging:Uri", "https://api.something.com/"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TransactionLogging:Version", "1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TransactionLogging:Queue:Enabled", "True")
    };

    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddInMemoryCollection(confValues);

    var confRoot = builder.Build();
    StartupExtensions.YourExtensionMethod(mvcBuilder); // Any other params
}
```

Comment: can you provide the 'using' statements? 'MvcBuilder' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach to @datchung's answer with ASP.net Core 6 (or 7) Minimal start-up, it's possible to leverage `WebApplicationFactory<T>` to run startup. Note that this requires defining InternalsVisibleTo from API to test project for the `Program` reference to be accessible.

Sample test, using xUnit:

```cs
[Fact]
public void StartupTest()
{
    var waf = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    var server = waf.Server;
    // Optional: check for individual services
    var myService = server.Services.GetService<IMyService>();
    Assert.NotNull(myService);
}
```

The `.Server` call there triggers the test server and ServiceCollection build. That, in turn, triggers [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#scope-validation) unless "ValidateOnBuild" option has been turned off.

More about WAF internals in here: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-6-supporting-integration-tests-with-webapplicationfactory-in-dotnet-6/

All of this does require that your Startup code works in test scenario (it shouldn't connect to online services etc.) but that is also useful for integration testing too (e.g. Alba).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using .NET 6 with the minimal API (no Startup class).

My Program.cs originally looked like this:

```cs
// using statements
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>();
...
```

I added StartupHelper.cs:

```cs
public class StartupHelper
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

    public StartupHelper(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public void SetUpServices()
    {
        _services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>();
    }
}
```

I used StartupHelper in Program.cs:

```cs
// using statements
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
var startupHelper = new StartupHelper(builder.Services);
startupHelper.SetUpServices();
...
```

And my test (NUnit) looks like this:

```cs
[Test]
public void SetUpServices()
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new string[0]);
    var startupHelper = new StartupHelper(builder.Services);

    startupHelper.SetUpServices();

    var app = builder.Build();

    var myImplementation = app.Services.GetService<IMyInterface>();
    Assert.NotNull(myImplementation);
    Assert.IsTrue(myImplementation is MyImplementation);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Zunit.Dependency.Injection package]

You should be install to Xunit project then add startup.cs file in base directory .