# How to write test case for Configure method in startup.cs ASP .Net Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, startup, xunit

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     //Something
 }
```

I'd like to add test cases for the above method in .Net core startup.cs file.
is there any ways to do??

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? There're some general approaches when googeling, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482256/how-to-unit-test-startup-cs-in-net-core what's not working with them?

Comment: Hi, i just want to add test case for the application configure method on startup.cs.
in that link test case available for ConfigureServices method but i need some helps for write test cases for configure method.

Thanks for you reply.

Comment: That's to broad… All I can answer is: In your test a) call the Configure method b) Check the state you want to test after this call.

Comment: okay, thanks dude.
i shall try