# How to unit test service configuration with NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have the following in my Startup.cs file and want to know if there's any way to unit test using NUnit?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.TryAddSingleton<IUserValidator, UserValidator>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IPolicyValidator, PolicyValidator>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IAccountValidator, AccountValidator>();
}
```

As a result of no test coverage this file is failing Sonar Cloud code quality gates because it's untested but I am not sure how to go about unit testing this?

Comment: Well, what do you want to test here?

Comment: Have a look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482256/how-to-unit-test-startup-cs-in-net-core and https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2018/10/01/unit-testing-your-ioc-container/ . Not sure if this is what you are looking for.