# Mock IServiceCollection.AddSingleton<T>() method in C# Moq

Tags: c#, moq

`DataConfig` is `static` class for which I want to write a unit test case using Moq framework.

I tried to Moq below two things but was not successful.

1. Mocking `AddSingleton`
2. Mocking complete `ConfigureServices()`

I am not sure which of the above approach will be appropriate.
Can anyone spare some code snippets for the test case?

```
public static class DataConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ICompose<int, PlatformRequest>, PlatformRequestComposer>();
        services.AddSingleton<IConverter<TerminalGroup, TerminalFacility>,
                                                  PlatformResponseComposer>();
        services.AddSingleton<IDepartures<int, TerminalFacility>>(
        svc =>
        {
            var reqComp = svc.GetRequiredService<ICompose<int, PlatformRequest>>();
            var resComp = svc.GetRequiredService<IConverter<TerminalGroup, TerminalFacility>, 
                                                                     PlatformResponseComposer>();               
            var smsBroker = svc.GetRequiredService<ISmsBroker>();

            return new Departures<int,PlatformRequest,TerminalGroup,TerminalFacility>
                                (requestConverter,responseConverter, smsBroker, "http://some.dummy.url");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe just my opinion, but I would think your testing efforts would be better utilized outside of the startup class

Comment: @Jonesopolis: As per my project standards, each should have its own unit test.

Comment: So what's the error you are seeing? That you can't mock extension methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Unit Test Startup.cs in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482256/how-to-unit-test-startup-cs-in-net-core)

Comment: @Jimenemex : I have gone through the link earlier, but that didn't help me a lot.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride : Extension method can't be mocked directly.

Comment: Your DI framework is what you use to inject mocks; it isn't tested itself using mocks. That serves no point because your test would only mirror the actual implementation, meaning it isn't really testing anything.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I understand but can't bypass the code commit policy in my project. So  whatever can be tested in the method should have unit test.

Comment: As the saying goes, "a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of a small mind". I would honestly write a test that says "this is testing this method" by using `Assert.True` and adding a comment as to why. The policy will then just have to live with that. The alternative is just painful, for no gain whatsoever. Since `IServiceCollection` is effectively just a collection, it should be "mockable" with a `List<ServiceDescriptor>`, which provides all the necessary implementation. But verifying the contents after the extension methods are done, that's another matter altogether.

Comment: `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` is your friend.

Comment: Nothing in the shown code needs to be mocked in a unit test. Create a service collection. Invoke the subject under test against the collection and verify the expected behavior. Everything else should be done in an actual integration test. What are you even trying to test in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use here black box testing. Rather than trying to create mocks, try to look at the problem from an outcome/result perspective:

- If I call the `ConfigureServices` then when I try to retrieve `ICompose<int, PlatformRequest>` multiple times then it returns the same instance
- If I call the `ConfigureServices` then when I try to retrieve `IConverter<TerminalGroup, TerminalFacility>` multiple times then it returns the same instance
- etc.

```
//Arrange
var collection = new ServiceCollection();

//Act
DataConfig.ConfigureServices(collection);

//Assert
var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
var instance1 = provider.GetService<ICompose<int, PlatformRequest>>();
Assert.NotNull(instance1);

var instance2 = provider.GetService<ICompose<int, PlatformRequest>>();
Assert.NotNull(instance2);

Assert.True(instance1.Equals(instance2)); //If needed use deep equality comparison
```